# How many different circular bracelets can be formed from 8 red, 6 blue and 4 yellow beads, always using all available beads?

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

How many different bracelets can be made from 8 red, 6 blue and 4 yellow beads, always using all available beads?
Two bracelets are different when we cannot get the color scheme of the beads of one bracelet by rotate or flipping the other bracelet.
Beads of the same color are the same and indistinguishable from each other, ie. by swapping two beads of the same color, we will not change the bracelet.

Comment: Can you use multivariate weighted Polya enumeration?

Answer (score -1):

First you calculate the anagrams: 
$$\frac{(8+6+4)!}{8!6!4!}$$
And then you divide by the number of rotations ($8+6+4$) and the number of flips ($2$).

Comment: Have you taken into account that 4,6,8 are not relatively prime?